# php code to validate alphanumeric string

Tags: php, regex, character

I want to validate alphanumeric string in form text box in php. It can contain numbers and special characters like '.' and '-' but the string should not contain only numbers and special characters. Please help with the code.

Comment: what exactly should your validation result be and what did you try?

Comment: Show us some valid and invalid inputs

Comment: it is basically a "asset_details" input box in form. It can accept alphanumeric value along with "." and "-". If user will input only numbers or only "." or "-" then it should give an alert saying that not a valid input type. In short it should accept combination of alphanumeric and "." or "-"

Comment: For example, jay123: valid  1234:invalid  ....: invalid jay.kum:valid

Comment: @jayantkumar did my answer meets your need?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then when it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```
// Validate alphanumeric
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$/', $input)) {
    // Valid
} else {
    // Invalid
}
```

Comment: This solution is not working on Turkish language characters. Thank you

Answer (score 35):

Use `ctype_alnum` like below:

```
if(ctype_alnum($string)){
    echo "Yes, It's an alphanumeric string/text";
}
else{
    echo "No, It's not an alphanumeric string/text";
}
```

Read function specification on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php)

Comment: Just want to clarify that the "ctype_alnum()" function only checks if a string contains all characters, all numbers, OR both.  It won't work if you want to include only characters AND numbers as originally requested.

Answer (score 3):

Code:

`if(preg_match('/[^a-z_\-0-9]/i', $string))
{
  echo "not valid string";
}`

Explanation:

- [] => character class definition
- ^ => negate the class
- a-z => chars from 'a' to 'z'
- _ => underscore
- - => hyphen '-' (You need to escape it)
- 0-9 => numbers (from zero to nine)

The 'i' modifier at the end of the regex is for 'case-insensitive' if you don't put that you will need to add the upper case characters in the code before by doing A-Z

Answer (score 1):

I'm sort of new to regex, but I would do it this way:

```
preg_match('/^[\w.-]+$/', input)
```